# Copying postgresql local to remote database (both with password) - ERROR: option "locale" not recognized

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

Working with Postgres 12 / Windows 10.

Trying to copy a remote database to localhost with the following command:

`pg_dump -C -h remotehost -p 5432 -U postgres remotedb | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres localdb`

CMD requests for password 2x.

`Password for user postgres: Password:`

I input localhost first, hit ENTER, then input remotehost and hit ENTER again.

This is the error I get in return:

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config
------------

(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  option "locale" not recognized
LINE 1: ...ting" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LOCALE = '...
                                                             ^
ERROR:  database "remotedb" does not exist
\connect: FATAL:  database "remotedb" does not exist
pg_dump: error: could not write to output file: Broken pipe
```

- How to solve 1st error 'option "locale" not recognized"?
- Is the 2nd error related to how I input the passwords? How should I work when both databases request for passwords?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to copy DB from PostgreSQL 13. PostgreSQL 12 haven't `locale` option in the `create database` statement: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdatabase.html but 13 have: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createdatabase.html Remove `-C` option from `pg_dump` and create database by hands.

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto! Saved the day!!! Removing `-C` and creating the database manually worked perfectly, and it didn't have anything to do with the way I was inputting the password.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to create the db manually.
You can do in a one-liner by using `sed` to replace `LOCALE` with `LC_COLLATE`:

Your command should look like this:
**Note! This works only if you use script (plain-text) file format for backups**

```sh
pg_dump -C -h remotehost -p 5432 -U postgres remotedb |  sed 's/LOCALE/LC_COLLATE/' | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres localdb
```

Explanation:

Script dumps are plain-text files containing the SQL commands required to reconstruct the database. When you add `-C` flag to `pg_dump` the dump file will contain the following statement:

- Postgres 12 and older

```sql
CREATE DATABASE yourdb WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

- Postgres 13

```sql
CREATE DATABASE yourdb WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LOCALE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

By using `sed` we substitute the `LOCALE` word with `LC_COLLATE` in the pg_dump stream so psql will be able to restore the db locally.
This works even if `LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'` is missing.

Comment: Awesome, @Codrut!

Answer (score 7):

This was caused by me using the 13.x of `pg_restore` connecting to dbs that were 11.x (target) and 10.x (source).

So I just installed `pg_restore` 10.x.

```
brew install postgresql@10
/usr/local/opt/postgresql@10/bin/pg_restore --all-the-args-here
```

Next time I'll be more careful with the `--create` and `--clean` arguments to `pg_restore`.

Answer (score 4):

After testing Abelisto's suggestion I found answers for both questions:

***Answer to question 1***

As informed by Abelisto, postgres 12 does not have `locale` option for `create database`, while postgres 13 does.

postgres 12: [postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdatabase.html](https://postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdatabase.html)

postgres 13: [postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createdatabase.html](https://postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createdatabase.html)

Then, creating the database manually on the destination db and removing `-C` from the command solved it. Here is the final command:

`pg_dump -h remotehost -p 5432 -U postgres remotedb | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres localdb`

An observation is that I had postgres 12 & 13 installed but `psql` path was setup for postgres 13. Hence, no matter if I was trying to `pg-dump` between postgres 12 databases, I would get the `locale` error, since `psql` was using postgres 13 to run the command.

***Answer to question 2***

The process for inputing both passwords was correct:

1. Destination db password
2. Hit enter
3. Origin db password
4. Hit enter