# Restore old data to new version of Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres installed on a server (version 9.3).
I plan to change server and update Postgres to new version.
In my new server I have Postgres v.12

I have copied the raw data files from old server to new server. Data is pasted in folder /var/lib/postgres/12/main/

I am not able to see databases in new server with command /l

What steps should I take to restore these databases to newer versions from raw data file folder?

Comment: This does not look programming related to me - but why not dump the data from the old server, and import it in the new one?

Comment: This is related to postgres programming :? Dump and restore is not option due to space constraint.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356435/genrating-postgres-dump-and-saving-to-another-server

Comment: Why not use `pg_upgrade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work.

You have to start a PostgreSQL 9.3 server on that data directory, run `pg_dumpall` to extract the data (perferrably with `pg_dumpall` from the v12 installation!), and restore the dump into the v12 server.

Comment: Yes tried a lot but could not restore data. Installed 9.1 and did pg_dump and restore in v12.

Comment: Then it was 9.1, not 9.3. Look at the `PG_VERSION` file in the data directory.

Comment: Sorry it was 9.3, mistakenly typed 9.1