# I have a problem with postgreSQL; Can't restore dumped databse

Tags: postgresql, dump

I wanna restore a dumped psql file but i consistently run into this error

The command I run in terminal is:

```
psql -U postgres -f dumpall.sql
```

The error I run into is as follows:

```
psql:dumpall.sql:96: ERROR:  database "template1" does not exist
psql:dumpall.sql:100: ERROR:  template database "template1" does not exist
psql:dumpall.sql:101: ERROR:  option "locale" not recognized
LINE 1: ...late1 WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LOCALE = '...
                                                             ^
psql:dumpall.sql:104: ERROR:  database "template1" does not exist
psql:dumpall.sql:106: error: \connect: FATAL:  database "template1" does not exist
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052693/copying-postgresql-local-to-remote-database-both-with-password-error-option

Comment: This is going to need more information: 1) What version of Postgres did you pg_dump(all) from? 2) What was the pg_dump(all) command? 3) Which version of pg_dump(all) did you use?  4) What version of Postgres are you restoring to? Add the answers as update to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody wrecked the PostgreSQL database cluster by dropping the `template1` database.

If `template0` still exists, you can create it again with

```
CREATE DATABASE template1 TEMPLATE template0 IS_TEMPLATE TRUE;
```

If not, remove the whole cluster and create it again with a new `initdb`.